# pyparsing - how to lookahead for ambiguous grammar (timestamp with/without timezone parse)

Tags: python, parsing, lexer, pyparsing

I'm trying to use pyparsing to parse some timestamp types in a SQL dialect.

In this particular sql dialect, we have two timestamp types - with timezone and without timezone.

An example of without timezone: `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, `TIMESTAMP(3)`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TIMESTAMP(3) WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

An example of with timezone: `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, `TIMESTAMP(9) WITH TIME ZONE`. As you can see the only difference is that the ones with timezone need to be explicitly defined.

Unfortunately, The following matching doesn't work for pyparsing:

```
(RPAR, LPAR, COMMA) = map(Suppress, "(),")
NUMS = Word(nums)

TIMESTAMP = CaselessKeyword("TIMESTAMP") + 
    Optional(RPAR + NUMS + LPAR) + 
    Optional(CaselessKeyword("WITHOUT TIME ZONE"))
TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE = CaselessKeyword("TIMESTAMP") + 
    Optional(RPAR + NUMS + LPAR) + 
    CaselessKeyword("WITH TIME ZONE")

GRAMMAR = StringStart() + TIMESTAMP | TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE + StringEnd()
GRAMMAR.parseString("TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE") # Works fine
GRAMMAR.parseString("TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE") # fails
```

The failure is:

```
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 3814, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text, found 'W'  (at char 10), (line:1, col:11)
```

I think the error might be because this grammar requires a 1-level lookahead to resolve whether something is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMESTAMP`. When it couldn't match `WITH TIMESTAMP`, it took `TIMESTAMP` and ended(and obviously failed cause that wasn't the end of the string). What should I do in this case? Does pyparsing have a lookahead ability for me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to use parentheses around the inner "|" choice:

```
>>> expr = pp.Literal("a") + pp.Literal("b") | pp.Literal("c") + pp.Literal("d")
>>> expr
{{"a" "b"} | {"c" "d"}}
```

Should be:

```
GRAMMAR = StringStart() + (TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE | TIMESTAMP) + StringEnd()
```

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I had that in my code (which was simplified for readability for the question). Thanks for catching this! Also thank you for making such a great library :)

Answer (score -1):

One rule is more specific than the other because it doesn't involve the Optional keyword. The conjunction is ordered and thus we have to define grammar as:

```
GRAMMAR = ... + TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE | TIMESTAMP + ...
```

instead. I tried FollowedBy but it didn't work very well.